# How to get rid of files neither in version control or on disk from list in "SVN Commit"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I use the menu *SVN Commit*, it seems like tortoise remembers file it has seen before (being existant when using that dialog before, even if unversioned).

They are either reported as having a status of *deleted (+)* or *missing*.

The files in question are meaningless to both Tortoise SVN and me.

svn.exe status does not list the files, only files relevant to version control.

How do I disable the caching of filenames/directory names in tortoise svn that is not either under version control or on disk?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this behavior.  Do they go away if you re-open the commit dialog or press F5 (refresh) while the dialog is open?

Answer (score 0):

If a file has a status of **deleted**, that means it was once in your working copy (and under version control) and then you invoked `svn delete` on it but have not committed the change.  Once you commit that, it will be removed from your repository.

If a file has a status of **missing**, that means it was once in your working copy (and under version control) and then you deleted it via Windows Explorer (i.e. you did *not* invoke `svn delete` on it) but have not committed the change.

In both cases, if you really don't want that file to be in your repository, commit the change and it will be removed.  All statuses are [described here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html#idp21198656), and correspond closely to statuses shown in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Those files were never under version control.

Comment: To get either of those statuses, they had to be.  Did you perhaps _add_ them without committing, and then delete them?

Comment: No. I conclude that tortoise svn has got confused by files being in a directory with the same name as another. It must be a bug.

Comment: Those two directories had a lot of identical files with the same names.